# Why does my php page seem to load async?

Tags: php, html, cpanel, apc, ini

I have two cpanel websites running the same php script that parses a csv file, one on godaddy servers (site A), one on hostgator (site B). on site B, the html portion of the page renders and then it parses the csv, while on site A it parses the csv and then renders the html portion.

Any ideas why there is such different behavior? I would like to have Site A perform this script like Site B

They are both running php 5.4 and have the same execution time limits.

Below are the result of array_diff_assoc of php.ini arrays of name => local_value. The first is array_diff_assoc(Site B, Site A) the second is array_diff_assoc(Site A, Site B)

```
Array
(
[allow_url_include] => 1
[date.timezone] => America/Chicago
[disable_functions] => dl
[enable_dl] => 
[error_reporting] => 22519
[expose_php] => 
[extension_dir] => /opt/php54/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525
[include_path] => .:/opt/php54/lib/php
[intl.default_locale] => 
[intl.error_level] => 0
[max_execution_time] => 30
[memory_limit] => 256M
[mssql.allow_persistent] => 1
[mssql.batchsize] => 0
[mssql.charset] => 
[mssql.compatability_mode] => 
[mssql.connect_timeout] => 5
[mssql.datetimeconvert] => 1
[mssql.max_links] => -1
[mssql.max_persistent] => -1
[mssql.max_procs] => -1
[mssql.min_error_severity] => 10
[mssql.min_message_severity] => 10
[mssql.secure_connection] => 
[mssql.textlimit] => -1
[mssql.textsize] => -1
[mssql.timeout] => 60
[mysql.allow_persistent] => 
[odbc.allow_persistent] => 
[odbc.check_persistent] => 
[odbc.default_cursortype] => 3
[odbc.default_db] => 
[odbc.default_pw] => 
[odbc.default_user] => 
[odbc.defaultbinmode] => 1
[odbc.defaultlrl] => 4096
[odbc.max_links] => -1
[odbc.max_persistent] => -1
[pcre.backtrack_limit] => 1000000
[pcre.recursion_limit] => 100000
[post_max_size] => 64M
[sourceguardian.restrict_unencoded] => 0
[upload_max_filesize] => 64M
[xsl.security_prefs] => 44
)
Array
(
[allow_url_include] => 0
[apc.cache_by_default] => 1
[apc.canonicalize] => 1
[apc.coredump_unmap] => 0
[apc.enable_cli] => 0
[apc.enabled] => 1
[apc.file_md5] => 0
[apc.file_update_protection] => 2
[apc.filters] => 
[apc.gc_ttl] => 3600
[apc.include_once_override] => 0
[apc.lazy_classes] => 0
[apc.lazy_functions] => 0
[apc.max_file_size] => 1M
[apc.mmap_file_mask] => 
[apc.num_files_hint] => 1000
[apc.preload_path] => 
[apc.report_autofilter] => 0
[apc.rfc1867] => 0
[apc.rfc1867_freq] => 0
[apc.rfc1867_name] => APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
[apc.rfc1867_prefix] => upload_
[apc.rfc1867_ttl] => 3600
[apc.serializer] => default
[apc.shm_segments] => 1
[apc.shm_size] => 32M
[apc.shm_strings_buffer] => 4M
[apc.slam_defense] => 1
[apc.stat] => 1
[apc.stat_ctime] => 0
[apc.ttl] => 0
[apc.use_request_time] => 1
[apc.user_entries_hint] => 4096
[apc.user_ttl] => 0
[apc.write_lock] => 1
[date.timezone] => UTC
[disable_functions] => 
[enable_dl] => 1
[error_reporting] => 1
[expose_php] => 1
[extension_dir] => /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525
[include_path] => .:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php
[max_execution_time] => 120
[memory_limit] => 64M
[mysql.allow_persistent] => 1
[mysqlnd.collect_memory_statistics] => 0
[mysqlnd.collect_statistics] => 1
[mysqlnd.debug] => 
[mysqlnd.log_mask] => 0
[mysqlnd.mempool_default_size] => 16000
[mysqlnd.net_cmd_buffer_size] => 4096
[mysqlnd.net_read_buffer_size] => 32768
[mysqlnd.net_read_timeout] => 31536000
[pcre.backtrack_limit] => 10000000
[pcre.recursion_limit] => 10000000
[post_max_size] => 48M
[upload_max_filesize] => 32M
)
```

**Update 1**

In comparing ini_get_all, I have found that Site A has APC enabled where Site B does not... could this be the issue? Is there any harm in this implementation in disabling APC?

**Update 2**

I believe we can rule out implicit_flush, as both are set to false and setting Site A's to true does not change the behavior

**Update 3**

Included the differences in ini files

**Update 4**

I have set Site A's php.ini file to be the same as site B's, with no change in behavior, so maybe we can rule this out?

**Update 5**

Although it does not mimic the async nature of site B, using

```
ob_flush();
flush();
```

to flush the buffer seems to get it very close, but it is not a very clean solution...

Comment: You should consider to ask the question in http://serverfault.com/ it sounds like environmental issue.

Comment: it was marked off topic on serverfault...

Comment: @user3130972 Can you link the one on server fault? You may need to add more details to it but it can be reopened

Comment: [Server Fault Question](http://serverfault.com/questions/669896/why-does-it-seem-my-php-loads-async)

Comment: Serverfault is for "PROFESSIONAL Server Administration". Stackoverflow is appropriate here. Superuser would be good, too. Good question, tho you should provide more details (show us both ini's etc).

Comment: updated with the differences in ini files